# Useful Formulas Analysis on Manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

This is just a reference request. Does anybody has or know a book with a short handed formulary for Calculus on Manifold. I could do it, but surely someone already have done it better than I would.

It should at least have:
Definition of Hodge Dual, Exterior Differentiation, Lie Derivatives, Interior Derivative, Cartan Structure Equation, etc...

If you don't have any reference, could you at least tell me which formulas do you think would be useful to put in it? 
Thanks

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at Nakahara's Geometry, Topology and Physics. Being a text for physicists it is more formula driven.

Comment: Why don't you just collate the formulas you use into one place as you use them? A page of notes or a small TeX document or something.

Comment: @MikeMiller That was just what I was going to do, but I then thought that surely someone else already has done it and probably in a more clever way. "The art is long and life is short"

Answer (score 2):

Gadea et al's book *Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds: A Workbook for Students and Teachers* has a 56-page long appendix (Chapter 7) listing formulas used in smooth manifold theory. It probably has everything you are looking for, and more.